# How to refer to a htm file in a subdirectory using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

Using `hyperref`, the following two examples open either the HTM or PDF files, accordingly:

```
\href{subdir/file.pdf}{label}
\href{file.htm}{label}
```

The second one opens a warning window that says:

> You are in the process of opening the URL file.htm...

Once you click yes, it opens the file on a browser. However, the following:

```
\href{subdir/file.htm}{label}
```

Opens the same warning window that says:

> You are in the process of opening the URL subdir/file.htm...

But it does not do anything else. I'm using the TeXworks viewer, not acrobat.

Is there a reason this is impossible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I assume that you are talking of Acrobat Reader on Windows?

Comment: I just edited and tried everything in Acrobat. In this case, none of the htm links work.

It feels as if I need to tell hyperref to keep the link relative?

Comment: try with `run:subdir/file.htm`